# How to exclude folders/files with .npmignore?

Tags: npm, rollupjs, npm-publish, npmignore

I generated a lib folder with Rollup for my npm package.

This is my lib folder structure:

```
/lib
  /components
  /stories
```

In my package.json, I white listed the /lib folder in the files key like so:

```
// package.json

{
  "files": [
    "/lib"
  ]
}
```

What I wish to achieve is to exclude the /stories when I npm publish

So I added a .npmignore file with the following content:

```
// .npmignore

/lib/stories
```

But this isn't working, the /stories folder are still included when I publish.

Comment: The docs specify that if you use the `"files"` key the root `.npmignore` is not used (but .npmignores in subdirectories are still used).

What I'm seeing with npm v7 and v8 is that all .npmignore files seem to be ignored (not sure if a bug or I somehow have the wrong syntax), but you can negate patterns within `"files"` by prefixing the pattern with `!`.

Comment: See https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4069 (tldr: .npmignore in subdirs stopped working with npm v7 and v8).

Comment: Oh yea, you're right, seems to an issue with npm not reading the .npmignore

Answer (score 0):

You need a trailing slash to mark your `stories` as directory. Otherwise .npmignore thinks it's a file:
`/lib/stories/`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, might be an issue with npm